# ReactJs: Component does not receive props from the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setInterestsSelectionCriteria } from "../../api/calls/data/ads/ads-configuration";

export class AdsConfiguration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      " ~ file: AdsConfiguration.js ~ line 19 ~ AdsConfiguration ~ componentDidMount ~ this.props",
      this.props
    );
    // This throws an error
    // this.props.setInterestsSelectionCriteria is not a function
    // this.props.setInterestsSelectionCriteria([])
  }

  render() {
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ads: state.ads,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setInterestsSelectionCriteria,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdsConfiguration);
```

This is what gets logged inside `componentDidMount`:

```
InterestsSelect.js:18  ~ file: InterestsSelect.js ~ line 19 ~ InterestsSelect ~ componentDidMount ~ this.props {}
```

And executing the action `setInterestsSelectionCriteria` throws this error:

```
this.props.setInterestsSelectionCriteria is not a function
```

For some strange reason, the component is not connected to the `store`.
I can't retrieve the store state.
I can't execute action.
Both of those are not passed to the component's props as you saw.

This is how the app is set-up:

> store.js

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

```
// ==============================|| REDUX - MAIN STORE ||============================== //

export const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
```

> index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// third party
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// project imports
import App from 'App';

// style + assets
import 'assets/scss/style.scss';
import { store } from 'store/store';

// ==============================|| REACT DOM RENDER  ||============================== //

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> App.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { CssBaseline, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";

// routing
import Routes from "routes";

// defaultTheme
import themes from "themes";

// project imports
import NavigationScroll from "layout/NavigationScroll";
import { apiCheckToken } from "api/calls/auth/checkToken";
import { useAxios } from "api/axiosHook";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { actions } from "store/actions";
import cookies from "react-cookies";

// ==============================|| APP ||============================== //

const App = () => {
  const [axios, cancel] = useAxios();
  const customization = useSelector((state) => state.customization);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (!cookies.load("token")) throw new Error();
      (async () => await apiCheckToken({ axios }))();
      return () => cancel.cancel();
    } catch (e) {
      cookies.remove("token");
      dispatch({
        type: actions.SET_LOGGED_OUT,
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes(customization)}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <NavigationScroll>
          <Routes />
        </NavigationScroll>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> Routes.js

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

// routes
import MainRoutes from './MainRoutes';
import AuthenticationRoutes from './AuthenticationRoutes';
import config from 'config';

// ==============================|| ROUTING RENDER ||============================== //

export default function ThemeRoutes() {
    return useRoutes([MainRoutes, AuthenticationRoutes], config.basename);
}
```

> MainRoutes

```
import MainLayout from "layout/MainLayout";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./ProtectedRoute";
import { AdsConfiguration } from "views/ads-configuration/AdsConfiguration";

const MainRoutes = {
  path: "/",
  element: <ProtectedRoute Component={MainLayout} />,
  children: [
    {
      path: "/ads_configuration",
      element: <AdsConfiguration />,
    },
  ],
};

export default MainRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting both the connected and the unconnected version of your component and then importing the unconnected one. The connected one is your default export.

So, do

```
import AdsConfiguration from "views/ads-configuration/AdsConfiguration";
```

Answer (score -1):

Map it to `dispatch` function

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   setInterestsSelectionCriteria: (e) => dispatch(setInterestsSelectionCriteria(e))
});
```

Reference: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function

Comment: The object notation used here is recommended over the function notation: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops